# "Unable to reach the server" error

Tags: search-results

After executing a search that returns more than one page of data, I get an error when I click on "next". "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

The Apache2 error log shows:

```
apache2/error.log shows [Mon Jul 08 12:58:29.922448 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 4022] [client 96.9.90.28:57008] PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/vietfeir.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.4a976861044aadd15e2c85b9.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vietfeir.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/Log/file.php on line 216, referer: https://ccrmdemo.vietfeir.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fsearch&_qf_Basic_display=true&qfKey=082061e63d30f54afa566bb
```

All of my files have permissions set to 644 and the directories are 755.

All files are owned by www-data:www-data

This is intermittent. I sometimes do not get the error.

Comment: I would check the file owner specifically on `/var/www/vietfeir.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.4a976861044aadd15e2c85b9.log`.  If you're working on the command line, it's very likely that file was created with a user other than www-data.

Comment: All files are owned by www-data:www-data

Comment: I did chown -R www-data: www-data on the site directory. The error message has gone away so that file  had the wrong ownership..The network error is still therr

Comment: now that the permissions issue is resolved, does that log file, or other more recent log files, have any recent entries that might help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Not the Apache log. Does CiviCRM have a log I should be looking in?

Comment: I've reviewed how logging works. Is there a CiviCRM log I should be looking at?

Comment: It's possible you have FULL_GROUP_BY mode enabled in mysql & that is causing problems - the log file should be /var/www/vietfeir.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.4a976861044aadd15e2c85b9.log (or similar) and have more error details

Comment: Are you recommend that I disable full_group_by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eileen McNaughton wrote:

> It's possible you have FULL_GROUP_BY mode enabled in mysql & that is
>   causing problems - the log file should be
>   /var/www/vietfeir.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.4a976861044aadd15e2c85b9.log
>   (or similar) and have more error details – eileen 16 hours ago

I removed the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode and the problem was solved. Thanks, Eileen.